# Deleting incomplete cases across multiple rows in R studio

Tags: r, time, rstudio, rows, missing-data

Say I have a longitudinal data set as below

```
ID <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4)
time <- c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2)
value <- c(7, 5, 9, 2, NA, 3, 7, NA)

mydata <- data.frame(ID, time, value)

  ID time value
1  1    1     7
2  1    2     5
3  2    1     9
4  2    2     2
5  3    1    NA
6  3    2     3
7  4    1     7
8  4    2    NA
```

In this data-set, we have 4 cases with data at two time-points (let's say pre and post treatment)

Something I want to do is set criteria to delete any case that are not complete for **both time-points**. In this example, I would want to delete ID3 (who is missing timepoint 1), and ID4 (who is missing timepoint 2). Like below:

```
  ID time value
1  1    1     7
2  1    2     5
3  2    1     9
4  2    2     2
```

I am not having much luck. I've tried variants of complete.cases() or which() to no avail

I'm still new to R, and would be hugely appreciative if anyone could help me out

Edit: Thank you Ronak for answering my question. Upon reflection of my real data, I have encountered a second problem. My actual data is more reflected by the below:

```
ID <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
time <- c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1)
value <- c(7, 5, 9, 2, NA, 3, 7, NA, 8, 9, 7, 6)

mydata <- data.frame(ID, time, value)



    ID time value
1   1    1     7
2   1    2     5
3   2    1     9
4   2    2     2
5   3    1    NA
6   3    2     3
7   4    1     7
8   4    2    NA
9   5    1     8
10  6    1     9
11  7    1     7
12  8    1     6
```

Where I would **also** want to remove cases 5, 6, 7 and 8. These IDs have an entry for Time 1, but not Time 2. Hopefully this makes sense

Thanks a heap

Comment: `library(dplyr) ; mydata %>% group_by(ID) %>% filter(!any(is.na(c(time, value))))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you switch your data to wide format (where each time point is represented as its own column), then you can use `na.omit`. Using `dplyr` and `tidyr` functions:

```
library(dplyr)    
mydata <- mydata %>%
tidyr::spread(key=time, value=value) %>% # reformat to wide
na.omit() %>% # delete cases with missingness on any variable (i.e. any time point)
tidyr::gather(key="time", value="value", -ID) # put it back in long format

> mydata
  ID time value
1  1    1     7
2  2    1     9
3  1    2     5
4  2    2     2
```

Note that this will work (it will keep only cases with complete data for both time 1 and time 2) even when you have a time point missing without an explicit NA present in the data, like this:

```
> mydata
   ID time value
1   1    1     7
2   1    2     5
3   2    1     9
4   2    2     2
5   3    1    NA
6   3    2     3
7   4    1     7
8   4    2    NA
9   5    1     8
10  6    1     9
11  7    1     7
12  8    1     6
```

Comment: Thank you very much Rose - this has answered my query perfectly. I never would have figured this out on my own. Thanks to everyone for their responses

Comment: Happy to help! I love the `dplyr` and `tidyr` packages for common data frame manipulation stuff like this.

Comment: Thanks Rose - if you will humour me I have another question... say I was to add a third time-point. When I attempt to reformat to wide with **tidyr::spread(key=time, value=value)**, it produces the error **duplicate identifiers for rows**. I'm not quite sure how to adjust the code for three time-points. Would be grateful if you have any suggestions

Comment: That error isn't because of adding a third time point. Something else is going wrong. Do you perhaps have any cases where the same ID has the same time more than once? A quick way to check is to get the number of unique rows using just ID and time, and compare that to the number of rows in the whole data set. They should be the same: `nrow(unique(dplyr::select(my_data, ID, time))); nrow(my_data)`

Comment: Thank you again Rose - you are exactly right. Your code demonstrated a clear mismatch. I had thought this may be the case, but had previously filtered my data-set meaning the row numbers were out of sync. I was looking for the duplicate in the wrong place. Really appreciate you taking the time to help :)

Answer (score 0):

See the updated answer

```
# Eliminates ID cases with NA
mydata = mydata[!mydata$ID %in% mydata[!complete.cases(mydata) ,]$ID, ]

library(plyr)
# counts all the IDs
cnt = count(mydata, "ID")
# Eliminates any ID that doesn't have 2 observations
mydata[mydata$ID %in% cnt[cnt$freq == 2, ]$ID, ]

  ID time value
1  1    1     7
2  1    2     5
3  2    1     9
4  2    2     2
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Ash

Comment: @perkot see the updated answer to cover your updated question

Comment: Thanks to everyone for your suggestions - I've got to run from work just now, but I will test out all of the suggestions this evening

Comment: Hi @Ash - I've only just had a chance to try your solution now, it worked perfectly. Thanks for taking the time to help. Better yet, this solution allows me to modify the code for additional time-points

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily with `sqldf`.

```
library(sqldf)    
sqldf(' select * from (select ID, count(*) as cnt from mydata where value is not null group by id having cnt >1 ) t1 inner join mydata t2 on t1.ID=t2.ID')
```

You  would select those id having a count greater than 1 and who doesn't have NA in their values and then join back with the original data.

Answer (score 0):

@Ronak already provided

`mydata[!mydata$ID %in% mydata$ID[is.na(mydata$value)], ]`

For the second part, you can just group over each id and filter on their frequency

`k2 <- data.frame(table(mydata$ID))`

`k2$Var1[k2$Freq > 1]`

and then do something like

`mydata[mydata$ID %in% k2$Var1[k2$Freq > 1],]`