# Deleting/ rows if rows do not have atleast 2 recordings for multiple variable

Tags: r, longitudinal

Question 1)
Let's say I have longitudinal data for 4 participants over 4 years i.e. years 0,1,3,4.
My goal is to

1. check if the data has outcome variables (n1) recorded for at least any 2 timepoints.
2. If only one recording is present then delete; otherwise keep it.
3. repeat 1) & 2) for multiple outcome variables (m1)

data I have

```
ID  visit   n1  m1
1   0   5.6 0
1   1   1.5 NA
1   3   0.5 NA
1   4   NA  NA
2   0   6   1
2   1   NA  0
2   3   NA  0
2   4   NA  0
3   0   3.4 0
3   1   2.4 0
3   3   2.5 0
3   4   1   1
4   0   NA  NA
4   1   NA  NA
4   3   NA  NA
4   4   3.3 0
```

this is what I want

```
data 1       
ID  visit   n1
1   0   5.6
1   1   1.5
1   3   0.5
1   4   NA
3   0   3.4
3   1   2.4
3   3   2.5
3   4   1

data2        
ID  visit   m1
2   0   1
2   1   0
2   3   0
2   4   0
3   0   0
3   1   0
3   3   0
3   4   1
```

or this form where we create new variable n12 (0= <2 values present for n1 Vs. 1= >=2 values present for n1) & similarly m12. Later I can delete rows based on the values of these new variables n12 & m12.

```
ID  visit   n1  m1  n12 m12
1    0   5.6 0  1   0
1    1   1.5 NA 1   0
1    3   0.5 NA 1   0
1    4   NA  NA 1   0
2    0   6   1  0   1
2    1   NA  0  0   1
2    3   NA  0  0   1
2    4   NA  0  0   1
3    0   3.4 0  1   1
3    1   2.4 0  1   1
3    3   2.5 0  1   1
3    4   1   1  1   1
4    0   NA  NA 0   0
4    1   NA  NA 0   0
4    3   NA  NA 0   0
4    4   3.3 0  0   0
```

I tried [Deleting incomplete cases across multiple rows in R studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40078485/deleting-incomplete-cases-across-multiple-rows-in-r-studio)
but the following code gives me '0' observations in mydata as it will delete rows even if single NA is found across rows

```
mydata = mydata[!mydata$ID %in% mydata[!complete.cases(mydata) ,]$ID, ]

library(plyr)
# counts all the IDs
cnt = count(mydata, "ID")
# Eliminates any ID that doesn't have 2 observations
mydata[mydata$ID %in% cnt[cnt$freq == 2, ]$ID, ]
```

I also tried the long to wide format this did not work as I guess value in my case are multiple variables

```
library(dplyr)    
mydata <- mydata %>%
tidyr::spread(key=time, value=value) %>% # reformat to wide
na.omit() %>% # delete cases with missingness on any variable (i.e. any time point)
tidyr::gather(key="time", value="value", -ID) # put it back in long format
```

New Question 2): how should I code if I want to have only rows with visit =0 value of n1 and at least one other visit (1/3/4) recording for n1?  to get data like this:

```
ID  visit   n1  
1   0   5.6 
1   1   1.5 
1   3   0.5 
1   4   NA  
3   0   3.4 
3   1   2.4 
3   3   2.5 
3   4   1
```

Kindly suggest R syntax or method to achieve goals
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dat <- structure(list(
  ID = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "3", "4", "4", "4", "4"),
  visit = c("0", "1", "3", "4", "0", "1", "3", "4", "0", "1", "3", "4", "0", "1", "3","4"),
  n1 = c("5.6", "1.5", "0.5", NA, "6", NA, NA, NA, "3.4","2.4", "2.5", "1", NA, NA, NA, "3.3"),
  m1 = c("0", NA, NA, NA, "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", NA, NA, NA, "0")),
  row.names = 2:17, class = "data.frame")

library(dplyr)

dat %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(sum(!is.na(n1)) >= 2) %>%
  assign("data1", ., inherits = TRUE)
data1
#> # A tibble: 8 x 4
#> # Groups:   ID [2]
#>   ID    visit n1    m1   
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1 1     0     5.6   0    
#> 2 1     1     1.5   <NA> 
#> 3 1     3     0.5   <NA> 
#> 4 1     4     <NA>  <NA> 
#> 5 3     0     3.4   0    
#> 6 3     1     2.4   0    
#> 7 3     3     2.5   0    
#> 8 3     4     1     1

dat %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(sum(!is.na(m1)) >= 2) %>%
  assign("data2", ., inherits = TRUE)
data2
#> # A tibble: 8 x 4
#> # Groups:   ID [2]
#>   ID    visit n1    m1   
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1 2     0     6     1    
#> 2 2     1     <NA>  0    
#> 3 2     3     <NA>  0    
#> 4 2     4     <NA>  0    
#> 5 3     0     3.4   0    
#> 6 3     1     2.4   0    
#> 7 3     3     2.5   0    
#> 8 3     4     1     1

dat %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(n12 = ifelse(sum(!is.na(n1)) >= 2, 1, 0)) %>%
  mutate(m12 = ifelse(sum(!is.na(m1)) >= 2, 1, 0))
#> # A tibble: 16 x 6
#> # Groups:   ID [4]
#>    ID    visit n1    m1      n12   m12
#>    <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1 1     0     5.6   0         1     0
#>  2 1     1     1.5   <NA>      1     0
#>  3 1     3     0.5   <NA>      1     0
#>  4 1     4     <NA>  <NA>      1     0
#>  5 2     0     6     1         0     1
#>  6 2     1     <NA>  0         0     1
#>  7 2     3     <NA>  0         0     1
#>  8 2     4     <NA>  0         0     1
#>  9 3     0     3.4   0         1     1
#> 10 3     1     2.4   0         1     1
#> 11 3     3     2.5   0         1     1
#> 12 3     4     1     1         1     1
#> 13 4     0     <NA>  <NA>      0     0
#> 14 4     1     <NA>  <NA>      0     0
#> 15 4     3     <NA>  <NA>      0     0
#> 16 4     4     3.3   0         0     0
Created on 2021-12-16 by the reprex package (v2.0.1)
```

Demonstration of behavior:

```
# Let's look at one ID
# group_by() is essentially doing the same thing
# i.e., summarizing by group
id1 <- dat[dat$ID==1,]
id1
#>   ID visit   n1   m1
#> 2  1     0  5.6    0
#> 3  1     1  1.5 <NA>
#> 4  1     3  0.5 <NA>
#> 5  1     4 <NA> <NA>

# Test for NA in variable n1
is.na(id1$n1)
#> [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE

# Identify values that aren't NA
!is.na(id1$n1)
#> [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE

# Count values that aren't NA
sum(!is.na(id1$n1))
#> [1] 3

# For the first approach:
#
# Filter() keeps values that meet the criteria
# In this case, we are keeping IDs with more than 2 non-NAs in the focal variable (n1)
#
# Create object in the environment based on this dplyr chain
# named "data2";
# using data from dplyr chain ".";
# inherits=TRUE makes it available outside of the chain
assign(x="data1", value=., inherits=TRUE)

# For the second approach:
#
# If the number of non-NAs is greater than 2 (per your criteria),
# return a 1, otherwise 0, in a new column
# A result of 1 here indicates this ID has two or more values that are non-NA
ifelse(test=sum(!is.na(id1$n1)) >= 2, yes=1, no=0)
#> [1] 1
```

Comment: Thanks! this code worked. However, how can I verify it did what I want? any cross verification syntax? or could you explain line of code (e.g. code line "group_by(ID)" =we are asking to group by ID, " %>%"=within data,  "filter(sum(!is.na(n1)) >= 2)"= filter within the previous set if sum is >=2, "!is.na(n1)"=not NA in n1, etc.)

Comment: You're welcome! I'm not sure what 'cross verification syntax' is, but I added another chunk to my answer with a demonstration of the behavior of the code and some notes. Let me know if anything still isn't clear.

Comment: Thanks again! I was confused in understanding the meaning of lines of code provided. confusion 1) in line "filter(sum(!is.na(n1)) >= 2) %>%": I thought sum function would sum all non-NA values within variable n1. If that sum total is more than/equal 2 then it will filter those rows. e.g. when 5.6+1.5+0.5=7.6, sum 7.6>2 then it will keep ID1; whereas when let's say 0.1+0.2+0.5=0.8, sum 0.8 <2, so it'll not keep it.

Comment: There's a lot of nesting, so it is kinda confusing. I tried to decompose the nestedness in my demo above. `!is.na(n1)` returns a vector of logicals ("which values are not NA"). `sum(!is.na(n1))` returns the count of `TRUE` ("count values that are not NA"). Then we compare that count to your criteria (i.e., >2). This returns a single TRUE ("the number of values that are not NA is greater than two") or FALSE ("the number of values that are not NA is less than two"), which is used to filter `df`. This is all happening WITHIN each ID, because we specified `group_by(ID)`.

Comment: I see! it's summing 'counts' of data in n1 and NOT 'values' within n1. That's what I wanted; so great job! Suppose we want to sum up the values of variables by ID then how different the could would be? Also could you explain the next line of code "assign("data2", ., inherits = TRUE"?

Comment: To sum values by ID, you could use `summarize(sum = sum(n1, na.rm=TRUE))` instead of `filter()`. `assign()` creates a new object in your environment with the name "data2" and the value of the preceding dplyr chain (i.e., the result of group_by and filter), which is indicated by the ".". inherits=TRUE makes this object available outside of the dplyr chain. FYI, using `assign()` usually isn't the safest/most stable solution... there's lots of discussion about this on the site. But I wouldn't sweat it in this case.

Comment: Okay. FYI:``` long0 %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarize(sum = sum(n1, na.rm=TRUE)) %>%
  assign("screat_least2.1", ., inherits = TRUE)``` only gives me 1 sum value (1 row 1 observation). on the other hand , filter seems to gives me what I want

Comment: New Question: how should I code if I want to have only rows with visit =0 value of n1 and at least one other visit (1/3/4) recording for n1?  to get data like to                                        ID  visit   n1  
1   0   5.6 
1   1   1.5 
1   3   0.5 
1   4   NA  
3   0   3.4 
3   1   2.4 
3   3   2.5 
3   4   1